# Changing int[] to IntArray cause not loading the images in application

Tags: java, android, int

I change this int[]

```
    int[] imageID;
        = {
        R.drawable.farm_small,
        R.drawable.scroll_small,
        R.drawable.desert_small,
        R.drawable.bg_blue_small,
        R.drawable.city_small,
        R.drawable.clip_small,
        R.drawable.grass_small,
        R.drawable.green_leaves_small,
        R.drawable.moon_landscape_small,
        R.drawable.prismatic_floruish_small,
        R.drawable.technologic_small,
        R.drawable.white_small,
        R.drawable.red_small,
        R.drawable.bllue_small,
        R.drawable.yellow_small
};
```

to this in string.xml

```
<array name="drawable_positions">
    <item>@drawable/farm_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/scroll_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/desert_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/bg_blue_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/city_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/clip_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/grass_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/green_leaves_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/moon_landscape_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/prismatic_floruish_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/technologic_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/white_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/red_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/bllue_small</item>
    <item>@drawable/yellow_small</item>
</array>
```

and I init everything here: `imageID = res.getIntArray(R.array.drawable_positions);`

But now when I join menu with this images I can't see them. I don't know why.

Here is myAdapter:

```
RecyclerViewForBackground mAdapter = new RecyclerViewForBackground(web, imageID);
```

and here is constructor for it:

```
RecyclerViewForBackground(String[] web, int[] img) {
    this.web = web;
    this.img = img;
}
```

Comment: What are the values in imageID after calling res.getIntArray()?

Comment: See @UneXp answer. And for consistency, you shouldn't put this in `string.xml`, as that should contain string resources. Create another file and call it `integer.xml` or `array.xml` or `resources.xml` or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [integer-array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray) tag instead of *array*

Comment: so the best way will be create another strings.xml like integer.xml and here put the <integer-array> and next try to get from it my [] ? i try this today i hope this help me